# How to maintain image aspect ratio in storyboard?

Tags: xcode

I have a UIButton in my storyboard with a custom image. I want to shrink the size of it but when I grab the corner and decrease its size it moves the height and width independently, making it hard to make sure it maintains the same ratios as the original:

[image]

Anybody know how to make sure the aspect ratios stay the same in the storyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hold down the SHIFT key while resizing to maintain aspect ratio.